# Why are induction motors controlled with a constant V/f?

Tags: motor, control, induction-motor

It seems that induction motors are always controlled using a constant ratio of voltage over frequency. Why is that? Take the classic torque-speed characteristic curve - varying the frequency shifts it sideways such that it's possible to start the machine, and control it at any operating point within the frequency and rated torque limits. What advantage does that give?

Comment: Nowadays, IM are not controlled using the constant V/Hz mode but the Field-Oriented Control method instead.  This allows to independently control machine flux and torque.  For example, there is no reason to maintain the high (standard) air-gap flux if machine loading is low.  This just increases core losses and decreases overall power conversion efficiency.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For an AC machine, the air gap flux is proportional to voltage and inversely proportional to frequency.  (Note that \$\frac{V}{Hz}\$ can be converted to \$\frac{V}{rad/sec}\$ which is equivalent to \$V\cdot s\$, or Volt-seconds.  \$1 V\cdot s\$ is equivalent to 1 Weber, which is the unit for magnetic flux.)

So, if you maintain a constant ratio of voltage to speed, you maintain a constant air gap flux.  Because torque is proportional to air gap flux, by maintaining a constant \$\frac{V}{Hz}\$ ratio, you can essentially make torque independent of speed in an AC motor.  So you can maintain constant torque down to very low speeds.  As Andy aka said, if you only reduce the frequency to change speed, your flux increases and you end up saturating the steel and you aren't able to maintain constant torque.

Answer (score 5):

Magnetic cores saturate when the flux density reaches a certain limit, determined by the core material, size, and geometry. When the core saturates, the windings stop looking like an inductor and start looking like a wire. This generally makes the current through the windings shoot up dramatically, resulting in higher losses and possible hardware damage. And since there's no more magnetic flux being stored in the core, no actual useful work is being done with that extra current. Saturating the core, in general, is a bad thing.

A given coil around a core will have a maximum volt-second product; this tells you the point at which the core will saturate. If the volt-second product for a winding was 10 Vs, You could apply 1V for 10 seconds, or 10V for 1 second, or 100V for .1 seconds, and the flux density would end up the same. (V=L di/dt, so if L is constant, and the product of V and dt is constant, di is also constant.) Since a motor is a winding around a core, the motor also has a volt-second product limit. Once you reach that limit, you have to reverse the voltage and flux up the core in the opposite direction to keep doing any useful work.

Since we're applying a sine wave to the motor winding, the half-period of that sine wave is the seconds in our volt-second product. If the frequency goes down, the period goes up, so the volts must go down to keep the volt-second product the same. If the frequency goes up, the voltage can also go up, because the period went down. Since frequency and voltage vary in the same direction, we can say the volts-per-hertz remains constant.

Of course, that's just an upper limit. We could run fewer volts without risk of saturation, and may wish to in some circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

If the frequency lowers, for a given supply voltage, the magnetization current increases and this can cripple the motor if the iron cores start to magnetically saturate.

Same story for a power transformer.

Comment: Thanks, interesting. So as long as the core does not saturate, there should be no need to control the voltage right? Why isn't the voltage varied only on the lower range of frequencies then?

Comment: I don't understand your last question in the comment you just made. Practical motors are made to be close to saturation at the rated voltage and frequency so there is nearly always a need to follow the V/f rule but it all depends on the type and make of motor.

Comment: Let's say saturation happens at frequency F (even though it doesn't happen brutally in reality). If saturation is the only reason of this control method, why isn't the voltage reduced from 0 to F (using V/f=constant for example) and back to a constant V between F and the maximum frequency?

Comment: Maybe you can give an example where I could answer specifics. Can you point me at an example where the V/f rule has some "anomalies"?

Comment: @user42875  It's normal for the V/f curve to go flat at the maximum output voltage capability of the drive. A given motor may or may not be able to tolerate a higher voltage.

Answer (score -1):

The induction motor is a constant flux machine. The air gap flux must not exceed the rated flux density of the motor. The over-fluxing causes heating of the core and eventually, the temperature rise in the core leads to core insulation failure. Therefore, for the reliable operation of the induction motor, the flux in the air gap must be as per the designed flux capacity of the motor.

The flux in the motor depends on the number of turns, voltage, and frequency of the supply source. The number of turns is fixed and it can not change after designing a motor. However, the voltage and frequency can cause changes in the magnetic flux.

But in any case, the flux should not change, or else the performance of the motor gets completely deteriorated.

As we know, induction motors are widely used with speed control with VFD for power saving as well as for process ease. The speed of the motor increases with an increase in the frequency. If we increase the frequency of the motor above its base speed alone keeping voltage constant, what will happen? Does the motor deliver the same torque? No- It can not. The torque is proportional to the flux and in this case, the ratio v/f decreases with increase in the frequency. Therefore, the motor operates in the under-fluxing zone and the motor will trip with overload.

Now, if we decrease the frequency below its base speed while keeping the same rated voltage, then the **v/f ratio** increases and it causes excessive flux in the motor that leads to core overheating and eventually causes insulation failure.

Therefore, it is a must to keep the ratio of voltage and frequency constant to maintain the constant flux in the motor.

A PWM inverter of the VFD simultaneously increases or decreases the voltage and frequency in the same proportion and thus v/f ratio is maintained constant, and the motor operates in the constant torque mode. It is possible to operate the motor in the constant torque mode from 0.1 Hz to 50 Hz by maintaining the V/f ratio constant.